# it's there a way to "compress" the following so it wont be so long

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, sorting

I put it in snippet to be easily visibile.
The code can be much bigger, so how can I short it out to have a faster response/upload of the page? Please help!

```js
LED0 = "";
LED1 = "";
LED2 = "";
LED3 = "";
LED4 = "";
LED5 = "";
LED6 = "";
LED7 = "";
LED8 = "";
LED9 = "";
LED10 = "";
LED11 = "";
LED12 = "";
LED13 = "";
LED14 = "";
LED15 = "";
var LED0_state = 0;
var LED1_state = 0;
var LED2_state = 0;
var LED3_state = 0;
var LED4_state = 0;
var LED5_state = 0;
var LED6_state = 0;
var LED7_state = 0;
var LED8_state = 0;
var LED9_state = 0;
var LED10_state = 0;
var LED11_state = 0;
var LED12_state = 0;
var LED13_state = 0;
var LED14_state = 0;
var LED15_state = 0;



request.open("GET", "ajax_inputs" + strLED0 + strLED1 + strLED2 + strLED3 + strLED4 + strLED5 + strLED6 + strLED7 + strLED8 + strLED9 + strLED10 + strLED11 + strLED12 + strLED13 + strLED14 + strLED15 + nocache, true);
request.send(null);
setTimeout('GetArduinoIO()', 2000);
strLED0 = "";
strLED1 = "";
strLED2 = "";
strLED3 = "";
strLED4 = "";
strLED5 = "";
strLED6 = "";
strLED7 = "";
strLED8 = "";
strLED9 = "";
strLED10 = "";
strLED11 = "";
strLED12 = "";
strLED13 = "";
strLED14 = "";
strLED15 = "";



  function GetButImp0()
  {
   if (LED0_state === 1) {
    LED0_state = 0;
    strLED0 = "&LED0=0";
   }
   else {
    LED0_state = 1;
    strLED0 = "&LED0=1";
   }
  }
  function GetButImp1()
  {
   if (LED1_state === 1) {
    LED1_state = 0;
    strLED1 = "&LED1=0";
   }
   else {
    LED1_state = 1;
    strLED1 = "&LED1=1";
   }
  }
  function GetButImp2()
  {
   if (LED2_state === 1) {
    LED2_state = 0;
    strLED2 = "&LED2=0";
   }
   else {
    LED2_state = 1;
    strLED2 = "&LED2=1";
   }
  }
  function GetButImp3()
  {
   if (LED3_state === 1) {
    LED3_state = 0;
    strLED3 = "&LED3=0";
   }
   else {
    LED3_state = 1;
    strLED3 = "&LED3=1";
   }
  }
  function GetButImp4()
  {
   if (LED4_state === 1) {
    LED4_state = 0;
    strLED4 = "&LED4=0";
   }
   else {
    LED4_state = 1;
    strLED4 = "&LED4=1";
   }
  }
  function GetButImp5()
  {
   if (LED5_state === 1) {
    LED5_state = 0;
    strLED5 = "&LED5=0";
   }
   else {
    LED5_state = 1;
    strLED5 = "&LED5=1";
   }
  }



// ..........etc............//
```

thank you, for your help!

Comment: Use two arrays.

Comment: Use an [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Comment: [Use arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/Arrays)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an array of objects and initialize it using a loop. Here is an example:

```js
var leds = [];
var nocache = "";
for(var i = 0; i <= 15; i++){
    leds.push({
                index : i, 
                state : false, 
                switch : function(){
                          var ret = "LED" + this.index + "=" + (this.state?"1":"0"); 
                          this.state = !this.state; 
                          return ret;
                      }
              });
}


function getURL(ledsIndexes){
    var url = "ajax_inputs?";
    ledsIndexes.forEach(function(ledIndex){
        url+=leds[ledIndex].switch()+"&";
    });
    return url.replace(/\&$/, "") + nocache;
}

console.log(getURL([1,3,4,5]));
console.log(getURL([1,3,4,5]));
```

From the code it seems like this app is used to control the GPIO of an Arduino board.

What my code does is to just create an array `leds` which contain 15 objects. The structure of these objects is like this: `index` to specify which of the pins this is, `state` to keep track of its state (`true` or `false`) and `switch` which is a function that returns a string ("LED[N]=[STATE]") and switches the pin's state.

Comment: Titus, you have right they control the GIPO, but I think your code replace all of my code or just a part of it? And so please be kind and explain further.Sorry for my english.

Comment: @RobertConstantin It replaces most of your code, what is missing is the AJAX call. From your name I'm assuming your romanian, I'm romanian to. Putem sa continuam conversatia in romana.

Comment: Titus, imi cer scuze de intarziere, dar am avut mult de lucru la munca. Iti multumesc foarte mult ca incerci sa ma ajuti. Crezi ca ai putea sa te uiti putin peste codul meu sa imi explici u mai bine ca nu reusesc deloc sa il scot la capat. Am aici tot codul: https://www.dropbox.com/s/w30ayqvx8927azz/index.htm?dl=0  https://www.dropbox.com/s/e0s8kmjinph821l/test.js?dl=0 multumesc foarte mult!

Comment: @RobertConstantin Nu stiu daca am inteles exact ce ar trebui sa faca aplicatia asta dar codul de aici cred ca contine cate ceva care ti-ar putea fi de folos https://jsbin.com/jexunamuxu/edit?html,js,output Am facut si eu ceva asemanator dar pt. Raspberry Pi. Am publicat aplicatia pe github https://github.com/saltimbanc/RPiProject Poti sa te uiti la interfaca poate o poti modifica sa o folosesti in aplicatia ta https://github.com/saltimbanc/RPiProject/tree/master/RPiProject/WebContent

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you might only need to store one array - the array of led states. In this case, you can just generate the appropriate request using a function:

```
// these are the variables we'll need
var num_leds = 16;
var led_states = [];



// initially, all leds are off
for (var i = 0; i < num_leds; i ++) {
  led_states[i] = 0;
}



// returns a single led's status as part of a query string
function get_led_str(index) {
  return "&LED" + index + "=" + led_states[index];
}



// gets a string that contains each led's state, for sending to the server
function get_request_str() {
  var nocache "&nocache=" + Math.random() * 10000;

  var state_strings = led_states.map(function(state, index) {
    return get_led_str(index);
  }).join('');

  return "ajax_inputs" + state_strings + nocache;
}



// makes a request to the server to update the leds
function make_request() {
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

  // send the request
  request.open("GET", get_request_str(), true);
  request.send(null);
}



// toggles an led on and off
function toggle_led(index) {
  var state = led_states[index];

  if (state = 1)
    state = 0;
  else if (state = 0)
    state = 1;

  led_states[index] = state;

  // send a request to the server to update the led (since it was toggled)
  make_request();
}
```

You will also have to update your html a bit.

Before, you might have had something like this:

```
<button onclick="GetButImp0()">Toggle LED 0</button>
<button onclick="GetButImp1()">Toggle LED 1</button>
<button onclick="GetButImp3()">Toggle LED 2</button>
<button onclick="GetButImp4()">Toggle LED 3</button>
```

Now, you can do something like this instead:

```
<button onclick="toggle_led(0)">Toggle LED 0</button>
<button onclick="toggle_led(1)">Toggle LED 1</button>
<button onclick="toggle_led(3)">Toggle LED 2</button>
<button onclick="toggle_led(4)">Toggle LED 3</button>
```

Comment: Thank you very much Brian, I try to implement your solution but i'm not good with java. the code you posted will replace only the led="" and var led state=0 ? thanks again.

Comment: Hi, I've updated my initial response with some code that might be similar to what you are doing

Answer (score 0):

Use a different data structure. For example, instead of having all those variables, use an array.

```
var LEDs = ["", "", "", "", "", "", ...];
```

However, this isn't going to have any significant impact on the speed (performance or download time) unless this gets really, really big. And if you're worried about the size of the file, you should just minify your code before deploying it.

Comment: Thank you very much sir! Yes, will be much better in performance when I use that on a small arduino with couple of kb of memory. Any other sugestions?